# Calculate fixed values according to the previous different value appearing in the matrix using matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a one column matrix in matlab like this one:

```
8
8
8
8
6
6
6
6
6
7
7
7
7
7
7
6
6
6
```

there is a value of 8 or 7 (random order), followed always by a series 6
I want to create a new column where I report exactly the value of the 1st column, except for the 6, that should change as 67 (if the previous number before 6 is a 7) or 68 (if the previous number before the 6 is a 8). This change occurs just for the 6, all the other values are reported exactly as in the first column. The resulting matrix should be this:

```
8  8
8  8
8  8
8  8
6  68
6  68
6  68
6  68
6  68
7  7
7  7
7  7
7  7
7  7
7  7
6  67
6  67
6  67
```

I tried with something like

```
matrix(matrix(:,1)==6,1) = 67
```

but this changes all the 6 in 67 and doesn't discriminate whether there was a 7 or an 8 before the first 6

Comment: What do you want to happen if a six follows another number, or if the series starts with a six? And what if a 6 is preceded by a 12 for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is not really a clear pattern, you may want to resort to a simple loop.

Example:

```
V = [1 2 7 7 6 8 6 9 6]';

V = [V V];
lastNonSix = 0;
for t  = 1:size(V,1)
  if V(t,1) ~= 6
    lastNonSix = V(t,1);
  elseif lastNonSix ==7 || lastNonSix ==8
    V(t,2) = lastNonSix + 60;
  end
end
V
```

This assumes you don't want to turn a 6 following a nine into a 69. Otherwise you can simply cahnge the `elsif` into an `else` statement.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you don't mind a small loop to iterate over the runs of `6`-values:

   ```
   aux = diff([a(:); NaN]==6); %// add a final NaN to make sure last run stops
   start = 1+find(aux==1); %// indices where runs of 6-values start
   stop = find(aux==-1); %// indices where runs of 6-values stop
   b = a; %// we'll now change some values
   for ii = 1:length(start)
       b(start(ii):stop(ii)) = 60+a(start(ii)-1);
   end
   result = [a b];
   ```

   As pointed out by @Dennis, if digits other than 7, 8 can precede a 6, this solution automatically handles that.
2. You can get rid of the loop, but that requires complicating things a bit. First four lines are the same as before:

   ```
   aux = diff([a(:); NaN]==6); %// add a final NaN to make sure last run stops
   start = 1+find(aux==1); %// indices where runs of 6-values start
   stop = find(aux==-1); %// indices where runs of 6-values stop
   b = a; %// we'll now change some values
   w = a(start-1)==7; %// which runs of 6-values should be 67
   ind = any(bsxfun(@ge, 1:numel(a), start(w)) & bsxfun(@le, 1:numel(a), stop(w)),1); %// indices of those 6-values
   b(ind) = 67;
   w = a(start-1)==8; %// which runs of 6-values should be 68
   ind = any(bsxfun(@ge, 1:numel(a), start(w)) & bsxfun(@le, 1:numel(a), stop(w)),1); %// indices of those 6-values
   b(ind) = 68;
   result = [a b];
   ```

   If digits other than 7, 8 can precede a 6, three new lines are needed for each digit. For example, for 9:

   ```
   w = a(start-1)==9; %// which runs of 6-values should be 69
   ind = any(bsxfun(@ge, 1:numel(a), start(w)) & bsxfun(@le, 1:numel(a), stop(w)),1); %// indices of those 6-values
   b(ind) = 69;
   ```

   Or, of course, use a loop over possible digits.

Comment: I believe the first solution would also produce 69 whilst the second does not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
%// Initialize the array
A = [A A];

%// Find the start/stop indices for all sixes
series     = diff(A(:,2)==6);
sixesStart = find( [false; series==1] );
sixesStop  = find( [series==-1; A(end,2)==6] );

%// Find the values just before the start of all sixes
prevValues = A([series==1; false],2);

%// Generate the new numbers
for ii = 1:numel(prevValues)
    A(sixesStart(ii):sixesStop(ii),2) = ...
        str2double([num2str(6) num2str(prevValues(ii))]);
end
```

Comment: It is nice that this solution also works for multi digit numbers, but it still feels like using strings is a hack. If you want to avoid it you can use this instead: `6*10^ceil(log10(prevValues(ii)))+prevValues(ii)`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: True, but I was implicitly assuming the OP was using `'6'`, `'8'` etc. as examples/placeholders, rather than his "real" data.